# NSScrollView jumps around, adds padding at the bottom

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsscrollview

I have an NSScrollView in a Mac app, which I'm iteratively adding (identical) subviews to. However, when the window appears, the bottom of the scroll view is visible, however, the scroll bar is at the top. Scrolling up or down initially causes the scroll view to jump quickly to a location, then it will smoothy scroll as normal. In addition, it appears to add a large, empty space at the bottom, but that could just be my code.

```
    for (int i=0; i<[userList count]; i++) {  ///user list is an array of ID strings
    PaneViewController *pane = [[PaneViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PaneViewController" bundle:nil];
    [pane setPaneID:[userList objectAtIndex:i]];
    pane.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, (i*pane.view.frame.size.height), pane.view.frame.size.width, pane.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.scrollView.contentView addSubview:pane.view];
}
[self.scrollView.documentView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.frame.size.width, ([userList count])*125)]; /// 125 is the height of the paneView
[self.scrollView.verticalScroller setFloatValue:0.0];
```

It shows the same behavior when the line

```
[self.scrollView.contentView addSubview:pane.view];
```

is changed to

```
[self.scrollView.documentView addSubview:pane.view];
```

Lastly, though I haven't tested it because the views are identical, my instinct tells me that this is going to fill up bottom to top, i.e., `[userList objectAtIndex:0]` will be assigned to the view at the bottom of the list, because of Cocoas whacky coordinate system. Is this true and if so, how do I fix it?

P.S. - The scroll view is set up in Interface Builder, if that matters. Also, using an NSListView instead of an NSScrollView is not really an option, for a number of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

- Where are you initializing your above code?
- Have you tried to setFlipped:YES or overriding isFlipped: and returning *YES* on all your custom views?
- Replace your

> [self.scrollView.verticalScroller setFloatValue:0.0];
>   
>   with

```
[self.scrollView reflectScrolledClipView:self.scrollView.contentView];
```

- You want to add the subviews to the document view.
- Have you tried setAutoResizeMask on your views?